# What is the "BIT VARYING" data type should be declared in Hibernate POJO class

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I am trying to map a PostgreSQL table in hibernate. I am writing a POJO class. There is one column with `BIT VARYING` type. How to declare java data type for getters and setter method in POJO class?

`Object` and `byte[]` are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use integers. Take the following simple example where I give bits representation for three different values as integers.

```
create table bits_comparison_test (
  string VARCHAR(10),
  bits INTEGER
);

insert into bits_comparison_test (string, bits) values ('Studio', 1); -- binary 001
insert into bits_comparison_test (string, bits) values ('Apartment', 2); -- binary 010
insert into bits_comparison_test (string, bits) values ('House', 4); -- binary 100
```

And then if we want Apartments and Houses, we can execute the following query:-

```
select * from bits_comparison_test where bits & 6 != 0;
```

Make sure that your binary representation, for each type, has only one 1 bit. For example if you represent houses by 3 (which is 11 binary), you can't know if the user wants houses or only (studios and apartments) together.

Comment: Good hint. But the original question was about Hibernate and a Java type.